# How To Recover Deleted DSL/PPPoE Network Credentials?

Tags: networking, windows-8, dsl

I want to recover my deleted DSL network Credentials in Windows 8. Is there any way to do it? Doesn't windows save these information in system logs? Please help.

Comment: I would hope not. Storing credentials in log files is a big security risk.

Comment: @user1326139 - Windows does save the network credentials.  If you are being prompted that means its no longer stored.  Just input the information again.